How to apply multiple estimator on multiple number of features to select the combination with highest f1 score?
I would like to run recursive feature elimination with multiple estimator algorithms on multiple number of features and keep the highest f1 score combination on the test data.
Instead of reviewing the result one by one, how to create a code that can generate and show the best number of features with the best algorithm on test data(highest f1, followed by the highest ROC)? My dataset is imbalanced.
I tried the code below that can generate result for different estimator on different number of feature. But I still need to review the result one by one. How to do that?
estimators = [('Logistic Regression', LogisticRegression()),
            ('Random Forest', RandomForestClassifier())]
num_features_to_select = [4,5,7,9,11,15]
    

for estimator_name, estimator in estimators:
    for n_features in num_features_to_select:
        # Create RFE object
        rfe = RFE(estimator=estimator, n_features_to_select=n_features)
        # Fit RFE to data
        rfe.fit(X_resampled,Y_resampled)
        # Get the selected features
        selector = X_resampled.columns[rfe.support_]
        X_train_selected = X_resampled[selector]
        X_test_selected = X_test[selector]
        log_reg_model = sm.Logit(Y_resampled, X_train_selected).fit()
        pred_test = log_reg_model.predict(X_test_selected)
        pred_test_1 = np.where(pred_test>0.5,1,0)
        logit_roc_auc = roc_auc_score(Y_test, pred_test)
        fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(Y_test, pred_test)
        precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(Y_test, pred_test)
        # Evaluate model performance using cross-validation
        scores = cross_val_score(estimator, X_resampled[selected_features], Y_resampled, cv=5)
        # Print results
        print(f'Estimator: {estimator_name}, Number of Features: {n_features}, Mean CV Score: {scores.mean()}')
        print(f'Estimator: {estimator_name}, Number of Features: {n_features}, ROC: {logit_roc_auc}')
        print(f'Estimator: {estimator_name}, Number of Features: {n_features}, f1 score: {f1_score(Y_test, pred_test_1)}')
        print(f'Estimator: {estimator_name}, Number of Features: {n_features}, PRC AUC:{auc(recall,precision)}')


Why don't you store the scores in a dataframe and then select the best combo?
Below is a toy example with fake data:
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, f1_score, precision_recall_curve, auc
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

# fake dataset
X, Y = make_classification(
    n_samples=1000, 
    n_features=20, 
    n_informative=10, 
    n_redundant=5, 
    n_clusters_per_class=1, 
    weights=[0.9, 0.1], 
    flip_y=0, 
    random_state=0
)


X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'feature_{i}' for i in range(20)])
X_resampled, X_test, Y_resampled, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, stratify=Y, random_state=42)

# estimators
estimators = [
    ('Logistic Regression', LogisticRegression(max_iter=500)),
    ('Random Forest', RandomForestClassifier())
]

num_features_to_select = [4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 15]


results = []
for estimator_name, estimator in estimators:
    for n_features in num_features_to_select:
        
        rfe = RFE(estimator=estimator, n_features_to_select=n_features)
        rfe.fit(X_resampled, Y_resampled)
        
        
        selected_features = X_resampled.columns[rfe.support_]
        X_train_selected = X_resampled[selected_features]
        X_test_selected = X_test[selected_features]
        
        
        log_reg_model = sm.Logit(Y_resampled, X_train_selected).fit(disp=False)
        pred_test = log_reg_model.predict(X_test_selected)
        pred_test_1 = np.where(pred_test > 0.5, 1, 0)
        
        
        logit_roc_auc = roc_auc_score(Y_test, pred_test)
        f1 = f1_score(Y_test, pred_test_1)
        precision, recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(Y_test, pred_test)
        prc_auc = auc(recall, precision)
        
        
        results.append({
            'Estimator': estimator_name,
            'Num_Features': n_features,
            'F1_Score': f1,
            'ROC_AUC': logit_roc_auc,
            'PRC_AUC': prc_auc
        })


results_df = pd.DataFrame(results)


best_result = results_df.sort_values(['F1_Score', 'ROC_AUC'], ascending=[False, False]).iloc[0]

# best configuration
print("Best Configuration:")
print(best_result)

This prints:
Best Configuration:
Estimator       Random Forest
Num_Features                9
F1_Score             0.896552
ROC_AUC                  0.99
PRC_AUC              0.937778

